# Acesso de Activity via Arquivo Manisfest - Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, path, android-manifest

Olá, pessoal.

Estou tentando construir um aplicativo inspirado no pokedex para um desafio, e tentando usar a arquitetura MVC.

Estou tendo problemas para acessar as activities (que estão dentro dos pacotes que criei) através do arquivo manifest.

Segue abaixo código do manifest e das activities.

Alguém poderia me dizer **o que está errado no caminho referente a activity?**

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.pokemon">



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_splash_screen_pokemon_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <activity android:name="com.pokemon.View.SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.pokemon.View.MainActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.pokemon.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.pokemon.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**SplashScreenActivity.java**

```
package com.pokemon.View;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.pokemon.R;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    /* Timer Splash Screen */
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            /* THis method will run right after the execution of the splash finish */
            @Override
            public void run()
            {   /* The Main Activity will be started */
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

**Files Structure in the project**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o pacote (`package="com.pokemon"`) já está especificado na tag `<manifest>`, você precisa indicar apenas o que está "faltando". Note que o `name` deve iniciar com um ponto `.`:

```
<activity android:name=".View.MainActivity"/>
```

Essa informação pode ser encontrada na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro?hl=pt-br#filef):

> Esse nome é usado para resolver todos os nomes de classes relativas
> declaradas no arquivo de manifesto.
>
> Exemplo: com o manifesto `<manifest package="com.example.myapp">`,
> uma atividade declarada como `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">` é
> resolvida como sendo `com.example.myapp.MainActivity`.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda. O problema na verdade era uns pacotes que tinha renomeado (acredito que errado) e o Android Studio não estava identificando bem o que deveria executar. Refiz o projeto com os pacotes do zero e funcionou.